# Grails how to add a closure with parameters to PromiseList

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to separate one task on a large collection into several threads each handling a part of that collection. However I'm having trouble passing it to the PromiseList. The code is like below

```
def extractTask={myItems->
    //work flow logics here, create some domain entities
}
def missions=//a collection of lists, each will be used as the "myItems" in the closure
Collection results;
PromiseList promises;
//trying to create a Promise on each list in that collection
missions.collect{myTask->
    Promise p=task{extractTask(myTask)}
    if(p==null)
        println "Promise is null!";
        promises.add(p);
    }
    results=promises.get();
    promises.onError{Throwable t->
        println "Got error in parallel keyword extraction.";
        println t.message;
    }
}
```

The code throws a NullPointerException:

`Cannot invoke method add() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method add() on null object`

This is a little over my head. In debug mode I can see Promise p is not null. Anybody please shed some light on this :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are getting NPE because the `promises` object has not been initialized.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia Mind elaborating on how initialization can be done please?

Comment: `PromiseList promises = new PromiseList()` I hope I'm clear this time.

Comment: Ooops...Thanks for pointing it out! I may never notice that :)